# Booting from Ubuntu 13.04 from CD stops

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to boot Ubuntu from a CD because my harddrive gave out. I see a little icon at the bottom and a little man, like it wants to boot, then the screen goes black and the CD stops spinning.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What laptop model is it? Some older laptop's have graphic chips that may not be supported (or detected) causing the boot to never get into graphics mode. You can modify the boot options, by hitting f6 at bootup to add other boot and detection options.

Comment: 13.10? Don't you mean 12.10 or 13.04?

Comment: I have upgraded this computer ever since v9 and never had to install any drivers.  Its Levenvo t61

Comment: Yes 13.04.  I tried http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076 but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not tried it yet, you could attempt booting using different options you can enable from the [Ubuntu CD/USB Boot Options Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Ubuntu_CD_Advanced_Welcome_Page_Options).

Press F6, and select ***nomodeset*** and ***acpi=off***. The image of this as below:
[image]

Space bar to select/unselect the option(s) you want to apply and then resume the boot.

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work. Same thing.

Comment: Try disable the **nolapic** and **noapic**

Comment: Will try this. Also I should note that its giving a single beep, which I guess could be a bad system board or bad boot disk?